# React Native: Setting flex:1 on a ScrollView contentContainerStyle causes overlapping of components

Tags: ios, flexbox, react-native

### Problem:

I have a ScrollView with 2 subviews and I want the first of them (lets call it ViewA) to have {flex: 1} so the other one (ViewB) will stick to the bottom of the screen - but only if their total height is smaller that the screen. Of course that if they are higher than the screen I want it to scroll as usual.

Case 1 (GOOD): ViewA with long text, ViewB scrolls with it. https://rnplay.org/apps/slCivA

Case 2 (BAD): ViewA with short text, ViewB doesn't stick to the bottom. https://rnplay.org/apps/OmQakQ

### Tried Solution:

So I set the ScrollView's style AND contentContainerStyle to be flex: 1. I 
Also set ViewA's style to flex:1. But when I do it, the ScrollView's contentContainer view is fixed to the screen height, thus not able to scroll if needed and even worse - ViewB overlaps ViewA.

Case 3 (BAD): ViewB sticks to the bottom, but the whole thing doesn't scroll. https://rnplay.org/apps/wZgtWA

If it's a bug - how to fix/workaround it?
If it's the expected behaviour - how can I achieve what I've described?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you possibly replicate the problem, or set up an example on http://rnplay.org/ ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes - here it is: https://rnplay.org/apps/wZgtWA . Note that even without ViewB, once you set `flex:1` on contentContainerStyle you can't scroll the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so i wasn't able to get it work by styling alone, but here's how I did it:

1. Measure the height of the footer after it rendered (using `onLayout`, and `measure`)
2. on the `measure` callback, I add the height (if needed) to a spacer view between ViewA and ViewB in order to place ViewB on the bottom.
3. In order to avoid showing 'jumps' to the user, I hide (with opacity) ViewB until its position is fixed.

my CJSX code (stripped and simplified version):

```
Dimensions = require('Dimensions')
windowSize = Dimensions.get('window')

MyClass = React.createClass
  mixins: [TimerMixin]

  render: ->
    <ScrollView style={styles.container} automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}>
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        ... THIS IS VIEW A ...      
      </View>
      {
        if !@state.footerWasFixed
          <View>
            <ActivityIndicatorIOS/>
          </View>
      }
      <View style={[styles.spacer, {height: @state.spacerSize || 0}]}></View>
      <View onLayout={@measureFooterPosition} style={[styles.extras, {opacity: if @state.footerWasFixed then 1 else 0 }]} ref='extras'>
        ... THIS IS VIEW B ...       
      </View>
    </ScrollView>


  measureFooterPosition: ->
    @refs.extras.measure(@fixFooterPosition)

  fixFooterPosition: (ox, oy, width, height) ->
    footerPosition = Math.round(oy + height)
    diff = windowSize.height - footerPosition
    if diff > 0
      @setState(spacerSize: diff)
    if !@state.footerWasFixed
      @setTimeout (=>
        @setState(footerWasFixed: true)
      ), 30

styles = StyleSheet.create(
  container:
    backgroundColor: 'grey'
    flex: 1
  spacer:
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  mainContainer:
    flex: 1
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  extras:
    backgroundColor: 'white')
```

It's very simplified code, (my view has requirements much more specific then this..) but I hope it helps anyone.

Comment: This is extremely contrived compared to Collins answer below. Only commenting so people keep scrolling.

Answer (score 57):

Try feeding `{flexGrow: 1}` to the [contentContainerStyle](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentcontainerstyle) prop instead

Comment: This should be the answer tbh

Comment: This worked for me but instead of flexGrow I used `flex: 1`

Comment: Thanks! It's better than ```flex: 1``` because ScrollView becomes scrollable

Comment: By using flexGrow as 1 for the ScrollView instead of flex 1 as suggested by Collin, the ScrollView remains scrollable and the child flex do not overlap. Best answer!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've made a sample [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/O4UxFA), and I think I've resolved the problem. The main thing I did was to make a main container view with two inner views, then set the inner views to flex at 80% and 20% (you can adjust to make it look the way you want).

https://rnplay.org/apps/O4UxFA

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I think i wasn't clear enough - I want viewB to scroll along with viewA when needed. I only want it to stick when the height of ViewA+ViewB is smaller then the size of the screen. ViewB should be inside the ScrollView, but if the content is smaller than the screen, I want it to stick to the bottom.

Comment: To accomplish what I think you have in mind, you will probably need to do some calculations based on various different things going on in the view, and rerender when scrolled. Take a look at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/ReactIOS/NativeMethodsMixin.js#L61-L63 . This will let you measure elements. Then you will probably need to calculate the view height with something like Dimensions or React Native Device (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device) and set styles dynamically .

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing just that, and managed to get an acceptable result. But it's so messy and I thought maybe it's just a bug or something.